How to give admin on a role to another user/role in PostgreSQL
PostgreSQL - Version 16.4
I am trying to change the password of a user (xyz). I have logged in as abc. abc has ADMIN and CREATEROLE privileges. I am getting an error -
ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
DETAIL:  To change another role's password, the current user must have the CREATEROLE attribute and the ADMIN option on the role.

I guess this means abc must have ADMIN option on xyz. How can I find out which users/roles have ADMIN option on xyz? How can I grant ADMIN on xyz to abc?

To find out who has the ADMIN option on xyz, run
SELECT member::regrole
FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members
WHERE roleid = 'xyz'::regrole;

To grant ADMIN on xyz to abc, run
GRANT xyz TO abc WITH ADMIN OPTION;


Thank you. I guess I missed something. The query fetched no data. So I created a new user and tried the same query. No records fetched. I first tried \du to make sure that the users exists, and then tried the query you provided. postgres@localhost # \du jayadevan
List of roles
Role name | Attributes
-----------+------------
jayadevan |
postgres@localhost #
SELECT member::regrole
FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members
WHERE roleid = 'jayadevan'::regrole;
member
(0 rows)
Time: 12.987 ms

You probably need a superuser to give abc ADMIN on xyz, so that abc can change the xyz's password.
